# Utilities to manage disk space

Tags: ubuntu-mate

Constantly having a problem with my Home volume filling up. The problem is I don't know what to delete. Is there a utility that will search for files by size and allow easy deletion? On Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

There are several similar tools for this. I prefer [filelight](https://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight/) personally, which is KDE/QT based. If you don't like that, another one is gdmap. If you want a console shell application, try gt5. There are yet more as well.